# XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange vs. addEventListener

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-apps-script, xmlhttprequest

Reading up on XMLHttpRequest for use in a Google Chrome Extension, and I've run into a question.

[MDN specifies using](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Using_XMLHttpRequest_from_JavaScript_modules_XPCOM_components) `XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener`, while [Google uses](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) `XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange` in their example.

**Is there a preference between these two methods** when making a GET request to Google Apps Script? I'm new to asynchronous Javascript, prior to this I've just been working in GAS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The preference would be browser compatibility. From the XMLHttpRequest API docs on MSN.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Properties

> `onreadystatechange` as a property of the `XMLHttpRequest` instance is supported in all browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Events

> More recent browsers, including Firefox, also support listening to the `XMLHttpRequest` events via standard `addEventListener` APIs in addition to setting `on*` properties to a handler function.

As Apps Script Web Apps will soon only support modern browsers (as native and emulated modes are depreciated) you can use either.

Answer (score 4):

`onreadystatechange` fires too much and you probably don't need to listen to it. Use [loadend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/loadend) (all cases including failure/abort), [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) (success), `error`, `abort` events instead.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest for more information.

Comment: You make a point. `onreadystatechange` fires on every state change, but `addEventListener` listens for a specific event (`loadend`, `load`, `error`, `abort`).

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you have control of browser type/version, you can do a polyfill using the object passed to onreadystatechange funcion:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
// This part for modern browsers
oReq.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress, false);
oReq.addEventListener("load", transferComplete, false);
oReq.addEventListener("error", transferFailed, false);
oReq.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled, false);
// This part for old ones
oReq.onreadystatechange = functionSwitch;
```

Where functionSwitch will call the right function (will choose between updateProgress, transferComplete, ...) so avoiding double code.

I have seen people using Windows XP yet and probably ANY addEventListener won't work. Have a look: [addEventListener Compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=addeventlistener). I didn't find a specific list of xmlhttprequest events via addEventListener.